# Not sure if proof is correct, question about Riemann integrability of a uniform limit of Riemann integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

I want to prove that if we have a sequence of Riemann integrable functions $f_n:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that uniformly converge to $f$ then $f$ is also Riemann integrable.

My proof goes (roughly) as follows:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, there must exist a natural number $N$ such that $|f(x) - f_N(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ (by uniform convergence) and there must also be a P of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f_N,P) - L(f_N,P) < \varepsilon$ (by Riemann integrability of $f_N$).

($U(f,P)$ is defined as $\sum (x_{i} - x_{i-1}) \times \sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f$, where the $x_i$'s are the partition points of $P$, and similarly for $L(f,P)$.)

I claim that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < (b-a) \times \varepsilon \times (\frac{1}{\alpha} + 2)$ (this would imply that $f$ is Riemann integrable).

My reason is that within each interval of $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ of $P$:

1. $\sup f_N - \inf f_N < \frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha}$ (define $\alpha$ as the length of the smallest interval in the partition), because $U(f_N,P) - L(f_N,P) < \varepsilon$.
2. $ \sup f $ is at most $\varepsilon$ greater than $\sup f_N$ and $ \inf f $ is at most $\varepsilon$ less than $\inf f_N$ (this is because $|f(x) - f_N(x)| < \varepsilon$)

Therefore $\sup f - \inf f < \frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha} + 2\varepsilon$.

It follows that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < (b-a) \times \varepsilon \times (\frac{1}{\alpha} + 2)$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: First, you messed up the definition of $U(f,P)$. Second, why are you concerned with equipartitions? That really is irrelevant. Where did claim 1) come from? It's really irrelevant, because you will have control when you sum over all the subintervals. But the spirit of the proof seems correct.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my proof. I have fixed the definition of $U(f, P)$. I know now that the proof doesn't require an equipartition but I thought that it could be useful; I have removed that part now.
Claim 1) comes from the fact that $f_N$ is Riemann integrable, why is it irrelevant? I use it to establish that $\sup f - \inf f < \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a} + 2\varepsilon$.
I don't understand what you mean by ' you will have control when you sum over all the subintervals'.

Comment: How do you know that each interval's $\sup - \inf$ is $<\epsilon/(b-a)$?

Comment: Oh, I see the flaw in my proof now. I think what you are saying is that we shouldn't have to worry about the bound on $\sup f_N - \inf f_N$ in each interval in the partition because the important thing is the (weighted) sum of the $\sup f_N - \inf f_N$ on the whole partition. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Trying to find a bound on $\sup f_N - inf f_N$ in each interval in the partition probably won't work too, right?

Comment: Thank you so much.